# how to change react-native slider looking?

Tags: react-native, slider

I have a question about slider in react-native.

I could have changed color of slider but I dont know how I can change slider's button(where you click to slide right or left) color, shape, style,etc...

could anyone give me some example how I can change it?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

To change the slider "button" use the `trackImage` prop to pass an image to the slider.

**Example:**

```
<Slider 
       trackImage={yourImage} />
```

P.S the full list of possibilities for the slider component can be found in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/slider.html)